# Who can perfom a nasal swab in California?

Tags: covid-19, guidelines

What are the guidelines for who can perfom a nasal swab in the state of California?

Previously I have heard from an MD that only a CMA, or LVN could perfom this procedure. If it helps I'm specifically speaking of naso swab for COVID-19.

I have not been able to find any details from CDPH.

THANKS.

Answer (score 0):

The US Centers for Disease Control and Prevention has [guidelines](https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/lab/guidelines-clinical-specimens.html) regarding how samples for SARS-Cov-2 testing are collected as well as *who* should do it.

The who depends on exactly where in the body the sample is being collected from.

> - Instructions for collecting an NP specimen (performed by a trained healthcare provider)
> - Instructions for collecting an OP specimen (performed by a trained healthcare provider)
> - Nasal mid-turbinate (NMT) specimen (performed by a healthcare provider or **the patient** after reviewing and following collection instructions)
> - Anterior nasal specimen (performed by a healthcare provider or **the patient** after reviewing and following the collection instructions)
> - Nasopharyngeal wash/aspirate or nasal wash/aspirate (performed by a trained healthcare provider)
> - Saliva (collected by [the] **patient** with or without supervision)

You asked specifically about a "nasal swab" which most likely be interpreted as an anterior nasal specimen. These specimens are simple enough to collect that anyone, including you, could collect it.

For the other types of specimens, the CDC [defines](https://www.cdc.gov/infectioncontrol/guidelines/healthcare-personnel/appendix/terminology.html) healthcare providers as:

> ... emergency medical service personnel, nurses, nursing assistants, physicians, technicians, therapists, phlebotomists, pharmacists, [and] students and trainees ...

In practice, the samples should be collected by individuals with appropriate training to mitigate exposure to the potentially infected patient, understanding of the anatomy of the site being collected from, and training to respond to potential complications of the procedure.